# Find linear equation by solution set

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

I have this question and I'm stuck , help me please if you can :
Find linear equation by the solution set :

U=span{ (1,2,0,1) , (2,3,-1,0) , (1,3,1,3) , (4,7,-1,2) }
So I did the following matrix but when I check the solution set in matrix calculator it shows different solution set which is lineary dependent.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
             1 & 2 & 1 & 4 \\
             2 & 3 & 3 & 7 \\
             0 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
             1 & 0 & 3 & 2 \\
            \end{pmatrix}
$$

I know its a stupid question but I'm confused and I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Well, the vectors are lineary dependent. So...

Comment: so I need to find who is dependent of the others and remove him and then check again ? I'm sorry to ask that questions but my teacher never taught us how to get equations from the span .. only to get span from the equations..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the linearly independent vectors. Then you will have
$$
\{(1,2,0,1),(2,3,-1,0)\}.
$$
You want to find
$$
ax+by+cz+dw=0
$$
such that its solution is the space spanned by $\{(1,2,0,1),(2,3,-1,0)\}$. You know that
$$
a+2b+d=0 ,\\
2a+3b-c=0.
$$
Then you have
$$
d=-a-2b ,\\
c=2a+3b.
$$
So
$$
ax+by+(2a+3b)z+(-a-2b)w=0.
$$
Take $b=1$ and $a=-2$. Then
$$
-2x+y-z=0.
$$
The solutiont set of this is
$$
S=\{(x,y,z,w);w \in \mathbb{R},z=y-2x\}.
$$
So the solution set S has dimesion 2 and $\{(1,2,0,1),(2,3,-1,0)\}$ are 2 linearly independent vector of S. Then $S=span\{(1,2,0,1),(2,3,-1,0)\}$.

Comment: I found out that the vector (1,3,1,3) is also lineary dependent by the other 2. So the remaining vectors are (1,2,0,1) and (2,3,-1,0).  the solution set became (2a+b,3a+2b,-a,b) so I marked x1= 2a+b , x2=3a+2b,x3=-a and x4=b and I just transferred everyone to the left side and got an equation that will fit the solution set. I think its right but I'm not sure

Comment: oh, you are correct. Let me edit this.

Comment: I found another way to find the solution set that this vector span , put the vectors vertically in a matrix and compare each row to the basic vector (this case R^4). then when you rate the matrix you will get a few 0 rows (except the solutions). then just compare the solutions to 0 (otherwise , you will have no solution (if all the rows are 0 and the solution is not 0)) I got 2 rows with these parameters that the solution set is spanned by this vector (checked it in matrix calculator too). intersting way tho. Thank you very much.